# Using Durandal how can you use multiple viewmodel files with a single view in order to break up a large file?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I have an application that utilizes a Google Map in one of its views.  This is a SPA that uses Durandal's view/viewmodel file structure using convention.  The problem I am trying to solve is that the functional modes that share the map view (google map) are quite diverse.  As examples the application needs to show the current locations of vehicles on the map, be able to show historical information (paths) for vehicles, and allow the creation, editing, and deletion of Geofences.  Each mode of using the map requires that some UX controls be hidden and others be made visible.

I believe that when all the viewmodel logic code is in place for the above, the viewmodel will grow quite large and therefore hard to maintain and code.  I am trying to avoid having a huge viewmodel file with logic for all of these UX controls.

Conceptually I would like to have multiple viewmodel files working seamlessly with a single view file so I don't have to repeat the google map in multiple views.  Also, I would like to maintain the easy/automatic binding using Knockout if possible.  What are some solutions using Durandal to break up a large viewmodel file while maintaining a single view file?  Is this possible or even desirable?

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward in Durandal, as this is precisely what it is made for. Your Google Map view will have a viewmodel, which you just `require` in the definition of your other viewmodels. Use a `compose` binding for each viewmodel in whatever your parent view is, possibly your `shell`. If what I just said was consfusing, I highly recommend the [durandal tutorials](http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/).

Comment: I already have a single viewmodel working with the view.  The problem I am trying to solve is selecting different viewmodels to be used with the same view depending on the mode the user is currently in (showing cars, creating geofences, etc.).  Perhaps I need to rewrite the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read up on [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).  Durandal uses requirejs as a way for structuring your javascript files.  Requirejs follows the [AMD pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailamd) which does quite a few things for you.  Allows you to create private variables by using encapsulation and prevents pollution of the global namespace.

There are also patterns w/ in AMD which you can have singletons or have amd modules that return functions used for object creation.  Much like how Class' are used in OO languages.  Javascript inheritance is kinda funky though.. so that might take some reading up on.. to see the different ways inheritance works.

So, once all your js files are broken up into a million little modules you will be like ermergawd... my spaghetti code is now macaroni code!

But have no fear.. your macaronni code can all be compressed/minified/uglifyed using requirejs' [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).  r.js can compress all your html/css/js into 1 file.. which could possibly be your entire application/site.  Durandal also provides an awsome [optimizer](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Optimizing-On-Dot-Net/) which will do all this for you automagically.